# How to select option from drop down list with selenium?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I have been searching different website including this one for solutions but have yet to have any luck, the website that I'm navigating with selenium is written in HTML4, I'm not sure if that matters but did want to include it.

The code I'm currently working with for this specific function of trying to select a specific option from a dropdown list is below.

```
program_selection = driver.find_element_by_id('pgmSelectList').click()
for option in program_selection.find_element_by_name('offerVB.currentProgramCode'):
    if option.text == 'New Maximum Care (Minimum 5/60 PT Warranty)':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

Below this is the current HTML element I am attempting to work with, I have tried without the '.click()' on the end as well because I have read a lot of places that I don't need to do that, but with the current code I have it actually opens up the list it just doesn't select an option, I have also tried sending arrow keys to the element to select something but I get an error saying the element has no attribute send_keys.

```
<select name="offerVB.currentProgramCode" onchange="return isProgramSelected()" class="tableCell" id="pgmSelectList"><option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
      

       <option value="COMMPLANS:2018-01-03">NEW VEHICLE COMMERCIAL PLANS</option>
      

       <option value="USDCOMMPLN:2016-09-01">USED VEHICLE COMMERCIAL PLANS</option>
      

       <option value="MOPAR75:2012-01-31">MOPAR 'TARGETED' OPTIONS</option>
      

       <option value="RAMADVNTGE:2010-02-01">RAM ADVANTAGE MAXIMUM CARE</option>
      

       <option value="PWRCARE510:2009-10-01">NEW POWERTRAIN CARE (MINIMUM 5/60 PT WARRANTY)</option>
      

       <option value="ADDCARE510:2009-10-01">NEW ADDED CARE PLUS (MINIMUM 5/60 PT WARRANTY)</option>
      

       <option value="MAXCARE510:2009-10-01">NEW MAXIMUM CARE (MINIMUM 5/60 PT WARRANTY)</option>
      

       <option value="MONEYBK510:2009-10-01">MONEY BACK GUARANTEE (MINIMUM 5/60 PT WARRANTY)</option>
      

       <option value="SHRTTRMLSE:2004-11-01">NEW SHORT TERM LEASE / RETAIL OPTIONS</option>
      

       <option value="POPWTN:2004-11-01">PRE OWNED POWERTRAIN CARE PLUS</option>
      

       <option value="POADDED:2004-11-01">PRE OWNED ADDED CARE</option>
      

       <option value="POADDPLUS:2004-11-01">PRE OWNED ADDED CARE PLUS</option>
      

       <option value="POMAX:2004-11-01">PRE OWNED MAXIMUM CARE</option>
      

       <option value="GAPINS:2004-11-01">GAP</option>
      

       <option value="CONVPLNPKG:2012-10-01">CONVENIENCE PLANS AND PACKAGES</option>
      

       <option value="MAINTPLANS:2012-10-01">MAINTENANCE PLANS AND PACKAGES</option>
      

       <option value="LUBEOIL:2004-11-01">LUBE, OIL, OIL FILTER PACKAGES</option>
      

       <option value="BUSNESSLNK:2005-09-01">BUSINESSLINK / SMALL BUSINESS PLANS</option></select>
```

How can I make selenium select an option from this list? This is the first time I have ever really used selenium.

Edit: I am currently trying this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("//select//*[@id='pgmSelectList']/option[text()='MAXCARE510:2009-10-01']").click()
```

I am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="//select//*[@id='pgmSelectList']/option[text()='MAXCARE510:2009-10-01']"]"}
(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Select class to do this work,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#Click on the drop down list to enable the options under it.
driver.find_element_by_id("pgmSelectList").click()
myDDList = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("pgmSelectList"))

#Pass the value to select
myDDList.select_by_value("USDCOMMPLN:2016-09-01")

#select by visible text
myDDList.select_by_visible_text("USED VEHICLE COMMERCIAL PLANS")
```

Comment: I tried implementing this into my code  and on the line that says driver.find_element_by_id('pgmSelectList').click() I am getting an error that says line 87, in select_by_value
    raise NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: USDCOMMPLN

Comment: This is the solution, I was just dumb and didn't bother checking if the "Used Vehicle Commerical Plan" was actually a selectable option in this instance.

Comment: updated the value correctly now and that method should work.